# Creating link on HTML pages

Tags: c#, html, tags

I have many HTML pages and I want to convert some of paragraph's words to link.

for example:

```
string paragraph="Bookselling is the commercial trading of books, the retail and distribution end of the publishing process. The modern system of bookselling dates from soon after the introduction of printing.  Compare retail prices & arrival times on your books - all in one place. Select which books you want - used, digital, or rental"

string []Linkwords=new string[]{"books","Bookselling"};
```

I have no idea about what I must to do, but this is my code to replace it to link...

```
1- Sorting Linkwords ...
2- paragraph=paragraph.Replace(Linkwords[i],"<a href=\"#\">"+Linkwords[i]+"</a>");
```

it doesn't gives correctly answer

```
<a htef="#"><a htef="#">books</a>elling</a> is the commercial trading of <a htef="#">Books</a>
```

is there any ready function or something like that.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use regular expression for advanced searching methods,
for example you can replace your code this this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> words   = new List<string> { @"\bbooks\b", @"\bbooksellings\b", ... };
        string pattern = string.Join("|", words.Select(w => Regex.Escape(w)));
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

I put the `\b` mean word boundary, to ensure that the selected is a word not a part of another word.

Comment: Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0):

That is because replace matches bookselling first, then wraps that with a tag, then it matches books and wraps that inside another tag. It would work if you match for books first, but then bookselling would never work, and similarly if you match for "books " with a trailing space then you wouldn't match in sentences ending with "books" or with other characters trailing.

I would use regex to do a search and replace instead, because you can check for a complete word instead of just specific characters:

```
var pattern = $"\\b{Linkwords.Join(@"\b|\b"}\\b"; // joins the words with \b|\b as a separator
paragraph = Regex.Replace(paragraph, pattern, match => string.Concat(@"starting tag", match.Value, @"ending tag"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention